# GAS [google-apps-script] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The Google Apps Script Developer Relations team chose [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) as their [Q&A platform](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support). In doing so, they use the following tag:

[google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

Web Applications, however uses this tag:

[google-apps-scripts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-scripts)

I'm in favour of using the same tag, used on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) and not to go with the plural form.

Comment: On [es.so] we adopted the [same tag](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed, consistency is nice to have. Merged and created a synonym