# Rename request: [google-drawing] to [google-drawings]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Google calls its web-based diagramming software `Google Drawings` ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drawings)) and we are in favour of [consistency](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2282/60716).

Please rename [google-drawing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drawing) > [google-drawings](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drawings).

There are at present about 23 Qs with the [google-drawing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drawing) tag.

---

Jeff is famous for (amongst other things!) his [tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105):

[image: Jeff's giant "S" tweet]

However it is official that the plural versions of tags are preferred in general and precedent that trade marks or the most commonly used versions are preferred, for example see [Rename [google-plus-circle] to [google-plus-circles]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/rename-google-plus-circle-to-google-plus-circles) and:

### [image: Google Drawings]

Without the `s` there seems [confusion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/107987/revisions) between one app and diagrams in a different app.

Comment: Could someone familiar with the topic write up a tag wiki description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All set.  Merged and synonymized.

Answer (score 4):

Since that's the official name of the app, and we're nowhere near the tag character limit, it should be changed.